# how to let a thread wait for destruction of an object

Tags: c++, synchronization, pthreads, conditional-statements

I want to have a thread wait for the destruction of a specific object by another thread. I thought about implementing it somehow like this:

```
class Foo {
private:
    pthread_mutex_t* mutex;
    pthread_cond_t* condition;
public:
    Foo(pthread_mutex_t* _mutex, pthread_cond_t* _condition) : mutex(_mutex), condition(_condition) {}

    void waitForDestruction(void) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(mutex);
        pthread_cond_wait(condition,mutex);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(mutex);
    }

    ~Foo(void) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(mutex);
        pthread_cond_signal(condition);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(mutex);
    }
};
```

I know, however, that i must handle spurious wakeups in the waitForDestruction method, but i can't call anything on 'this', because it could already be destructed.

Another possibility that crossed my mind was to not use a condition variable, but lock the mutex in the constructor, unlock it in the destructor and lock/unlock it in the waitForDestruction method - this should work with a non-recursive mutex, and iirc i can unlock a mutex from a thread which didn't lock it, right? Will the second option suffer from any spurious wakeups?

Comment: Leaving the design aside, what if you let the mutex and condition be created by the constructor, instead of passed as arguments, they would be unique for each instance, and you wouldn't have to worry about spurious signals. However, you then need to have proper copy-constructor and assignment-operator to create new mutex/condition.

Comment: Forget the missing `while` loop, you can't implement `waitForDestruction` like that at all. You're asking the object to examine whether it exists or not. You need to split the synchronization into another object.

Comment: I think you should consider creating a separate object which the first thread waits on and the destructor of the object in question triggers.

Comment: @all - yes i know that's bad design, the question was more out of interest than out of the need to actually implement it. @Joachim, i think that would introduce even more problems, like having to destroy the mutex in the destructor while the thread waiting in `waitForDestruction` accesses the mutex. @Potatoswatter: Hm you're right, there's a race condition if `waitForDestruction` is called after the object has been destructed.. Thats bad and probably impossible to fix. I guess there's a reason that you shouldn't do stuff like that :)

Comment: Hm another idea: could it be done with a semaphore (created outside of `Foo`) with capacity 1, grabbed in the ctor, released in the dtor. The calling thread could then try to grab the semaphore and will block until the `Foo` releases it. @Tom: Basically your idea, I think using a semaphore for that purpose would do the trick

Answer (score 1):

It is always a difficult matter. But how about these lines of code:

```
struct FooSync {

    typedef boost::shared_ptr<FooSync> Ptr;

    FooSync() : owner(boost::this_thread::get_id()) {
    }

    void Wait() {
        assert(boost::this_thread::get_id() != owner);
        mutex.lock();
        mutex.unlock();
    }

    boost::mutex mutex;
    boost::thread::id owner;

};

struct Foo {

    Foo() { }

    ~Foo() {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < waiters.size(); ++i) {
            waiters[i]->mutex.unlock();
        }
    }

    FooSync::Ptr GetSync() {
        waiters.push_back(FooSync::Ptr(new FooSync));
        waiters.back()->mutex.lock();
        return waiters.back();
    }

    std::vector<FooSync::Ptr> waiters;

};
```

The solution above would allow any number of destruction-wait object on a single `Foo` object. As long as it will correctly manage memory occupied by these objects. It seems that nothing prevents `Foo` instances to be created on the stack.

Though the only drawback I see is that it requires that destruction-wait objects always created in a thread that "owns" `Foo` object instance otherwise the recursive lock will probably happen. There is more, if `GetSync` gets called from multiple threads race condition may occur after `push_back`.

---

#### EDIT:

Ok, i have reconsidered the problem and came up with **new solution**. Take a look:

```
typedef boost::shared_ptr<boost::shared_mutex> MutexPtr;

struct FooSync {

    typedef boost::shared_ptr<FooSync> Ptr;

    FooSync(MutexPtr const& ptr) : mutex(ptr) {
    }

    void Wait() {
        mutex->lock_shared();
        mutex->unlock_shared();
    }

    MutexPtr mutex;

};

struct Foo {

    Foo() : mutex(new boost::shared_mutex) {
        mutex->lock();
    }

    ~Foo() {
        mutex->unlock();
    }

    FooSync::Ptr GetSync() {
        return FooSync::Ptr(new FooSync(mutex));
    }

    MutexPtr mutex;

};
```

Now it seems reasonably cleaner and much less points of code are subjects to race conditions. There is only one synchronization primitive shared between object itself and all the sync-objects. Some efforts must be taken to overcome the case when `Wait` called in the thread where the object itself is (like in my first example). If the target platform does not support `shared_mutex` it is ok to go along with good-ol `mutex`. `shared_mutex` seems to reduce the burden of locks when there are many of `FooSync`s waiting.

Comment: What happens if thread x calls GetSync while thready Y is in the middle of destructing... Bad things.. However I think you are on the right track, just need to simplify the design. Have Foo grab the FooSync mutex in the constructor and release in the destructor. Any threads that wait for Foo to be destructed will block on the mutex until the destructor is called. Since FooSync::wait() then immediatly calls unlock all the waiters will be released.

Comment: @Charlie About your first point: there is a known limitation I mentioned - no way you could call `GetSync` in the thread x in your example since the assertion will fail. This is inconvinient of course, some steps should be taken to make it possible.

Comment: @Charlie Just wrote a new solution, please take a look.

Comment: This looks a lot better, now the only "condition" you need to watch for is to ensure waiters don't lock the mutext before the object does.  This should be avoided by enforcing use of the Foo:GetSync()

Comment: and your comment about calling FooSync::wait from the same thread.